# java while loop help prompting user

Tags: java, while-loop

Im writing a assignment for my class in which it read if a SIN number is valid or not. I did all the math but I need help doing the output. I need the output to say if the SIN number is valid or not but if  it is valid or not it should repeatly asks the user to enter the sin number again after it checks if it valid or not and it should check if its valid or not. Can someone help me with this, it can be in a while loop, or for loop or if statement.

this is what I got so far

```
 while(total!=999999999)
    {
      if(n9==totalA)
        System.out.println("The SIN " + total + " is valid.");
      else
        System.out.println("The SIN is not valid");

    }
```

I just need it to ask the user to re enter the 9 digit sin number and check if its valid or not and if I enter 999999999 it will stop the loop.

Comment: what have you done so far? post some relevant code. we will not generate codes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an infinite loop like the one below which breaks the loop when the SIN is valid:

```
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter SIN number");
    //Get input
    if(/*If valid*/)
        break;
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid input.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any sample code on what you've done so far, I'll give you some pseudocode so you can figure it out yourself.

```
while true
    read sin number
    if sin is valid
        print sin number
    else
         continue
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a 9 digit SIN use while loop

```
//this is your input
String sin;
//you can do infinite loop
while(true){

//ask SIN here

   if(sin.length() <9){
     System.out.println("invalid SIN");
   }else{
     //if valid SIN
     break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I got so far

```
    while(total!=999999999)
    {
       System.out.println("Please enter your 9 digit Social Insurance Number");
       total = In.getInt();
    if(totalA==n9)
      System.out.println("The SIN " + total + " is valid.");
    else
      System.out.println("The SIN is not valid");

    }
```

what happens now is that if the first sin I enter isnt valid it will says its not valid but when it ask for it again I enter a valid sin it will says not valid??